# How to select unique pairs in SQLite3 and count frequency?

Tags: sql, sqlite

How to select unique pairs (a,b) (b,a) as one pair in SQLite3 and count total frequency?

For example -

Given table1-

```
 column1, column2, frequency
 a         b        2
 b         a        1
 c         d        1
 c         a        1
 d         c        1
```

to produce

```
 pair1, pair2, total_frequency
 a         b        3
 c         d        2
 c         a        1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
select min(column1, column2), max(column1, column2), sum(frequency)
from table1
group by min(column1, column2), max(column1, column2)
order by min(column1, column2), max(column1, column2)
```